# Close button in some default GNOME applications looks different

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, window-buttons

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. After a recent updates or something else, close button in some program looks different. I see it only in system monitor and calculator.

It looks like this:

Calculator
[image: calculator]

System Monitor
[image: system monitor]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those pre-installed applications in Ubuntu 18.04 are [snap](https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started) applications. They don't work well with custom GTK+ theme due to restrictions of snap packages. They fall back to a default GTK+ theme when there's an issue.

You may consider removing the snap application (for example System Monitor) by running

```
snap remove gnome-system-monitor
```

and install the traditional apt one by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
```

In general you can find the installed snap applications by running the following

```
snap list
```

and then choose which one to remove and get it replaced by its traditional apt counterpart.